# Wordpress redirect loop with MAMP pro on local machine

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mamp

I downloaded a wordpress website to my local machine and set up a host on MAMP Pro with an export of the live database, now I keep hitting a redirect loop on the main page when I try to view the website, it doesn't matter whether I reset the .htaccess file, clear all my cookies, delete my plugins or do any other of the recommended things it keep coming back. The official error is:

> This webpage has a redirect loop
>
> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: See apache error logs?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues. Somehow resetting the permalinks settings in the admin panel to plain fixed the problem.

Comment: the problem is that you can't even enter the admin-panel

Answer (score 0):

Are you using HTTPS by any chance? If so you may want to add

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

To the top of your wp-config.php file.

You might want to also check your database to see if the site url's are correct.

Answer (score 0):

As I was moving from Windows environment to Mac OS probably on the copy files i was missing the install.php file. And when i tried to install the theme it would bring me the redirect loop screen.

It was confusing to me because I was following all steps at the end I went to look for the install.php and saw it was missing there put it in the place and voila!

Maybe will help i don't know, for the next readers to come!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve an identical issue by doing the following:

- In the `wp_options` table of your site's database check if the port numbers for option_name `siteurl` and `home` match those of your server. Update them if not.
- Remove the port number from `$root_dir` in wp-config.php

This error occured on an older project running Wordpress 4.1 after changing the ports on my MAMP apache server months earlier. Hope that helps.